# meaning of '<%=j %>' tag in ruby view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I saw the tag `<%=j some-variable %>` in a ruby view file and I was wondering if anyone could tell me what the `j` in it stands for? I know `<%= %>` is used to print out ruby and `<% %>` is for using ruby code in a view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails views, `j()` is an alias for [`escape_javascript()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript):

> Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.

This is usually used in DOM manipulation, when you want to render another ERB template and use that output as a parameter to your JS function, for example.

If you are using jQuery, you might have something like this in your JS response after creating a new record:

```
$('ul#items').append('<%= j render(resource) %>');
```

This would render the corresponding partial for the resource, escape the result such that it can be used as a Javascript string, enclose that escaped string in quotation marks, and then append that final string to a DOM node.

**Update:**

(This is derived from my comment in discussion for one of the other answers.)

A lot of Ruby developers write the `j` right next to the `<%=`, without any separating whitespace. Some write `<%=j render 'something' %>` while it is common to enclose at least the inner method call arguments like this: `puts some_method('bar')`.

It was the same story with the `h` alias for escaping HTML before Rails started auto-escaping strings.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is shorthand for `escape_javascript`

```
<%=j some-variable %> => <%= escape_javascript some-variable %>
```

will try to find a source for this

---

here's the [source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript).  Note that this is only available in Rails 4.0.

So i'm not sure, actually - the context in the docs makes it seem like it needs to be used in connection with `render`...

```
$('some_element').replaceWith('<%=j render 'some/element_template' %>');
```

Comment: What exactly does javascript_escaped do?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Comment: It probably has the effect of calling `to_json` on the object in question so it can be used as arguments to a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `j` is method and `some-variable` is its parameter.
After method is called, the result of this call is converted to string and inserted into your view.

To be more precise, `j` is alias to [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) method, that escapes JavaScript characters.

Comment: Ruby's loose bracketless syntax can confuse people used to C, Java, JavaScript, Perl or Python where these are strictly required.

Comment: I highly doubt it is a method

Comment: @Kitty1911 Why would you doubt that? It looks *exactly* like a method call in Ruby. It's most likely a helper method called `j`. Remember `j foo` and `j(foo)` are equivalent.

Comment: I'm guessing j is a method defined by the template author for shortness of typing, possibly an alias for or proxy to JSON.generate or something.

Comment: @Kitty1911 if it's not a syntax error, it can *only* be a method.

Comment: @Kitty1911 of course it's a method call. Even if you didn't have `j` method defined, but `j`  local variable instead, this code would give you syntax error.

Comment: A lot of Ruby developers write the `j` right next to the `<%=`, without any separating whitespace. Some write `<%=j render 'something' %>` while it is common to enclose at least the inner call arguments like this: `puts some_method('bar')`. It was also the same story with the `h` alias for escaping HTML before. It's reasonable, I think, for people to wonder if the `j` is part of ERB syntax (especially having no idea yet what `j` does).